# LINQ or SQL to get records closest to specific time per day per account

Tags: sql, linq

1 table History with Date (date)
1 table AccountCategories with Account (nvarchar(50))
1 table Balance with Account(nvarchar(50)), Date(datetime), Balance(float)

I need a LINQ or SQL Server query to get the following from Balance:

(Date, Account, Balance) for each Date in History, for each Account in AccountInfo, the Balance for the last record before 4:10:00 PM for that date

My SQL below returns all records before 4:10:00 PM but I only want the last one for each account:

```
select [Date],Account,Balance from Balance where Account in (select Account from AccountCategories) and DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, [Date])) in (select DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, [Date])) from History) and [Date] <= DATEADD(mi,970,DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, [Date]), 0)) order by [Date] desc,Account
```

This LINQ also doesn't quite get what I want as 'The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.':

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(16, 10, 0);
var accts = AccountCategories.Select(u => u.Account);
var pastDates = Histories.Select(u => u.Date);
var dailyBalance = (from dailyBal in Balances where accts.Contains(dailyBal.Account) group dailyBal by dailyBal.Account into a select a.OrderByDescending(t => t.Date).Where(u => u.Date <= (u.Date.Date + ts)).FirstOrDefault());
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that calculates the row_number for a given day for the records before 4:10pm and then returns only the balance record before 4:10pm

```
SELECT [date], 
       account, 
       balance 
FROM   (SELECT [date], 
           account, 
           balance, 
           Row_number() 
             OVER ( 
               partition BY CONVERT(DATE, [date]), account 
               ORDER BY [date] DESC) AS seqnum 
    FROM   balance 
    WHERE  CONVERT(DATE, [date]) IN (SELECT CONVERT(DATE, [date]) 
                                     FROM   history) 
           AND account IN (SELECT account 
                           FROM   accountcategories) 
           AND [date] <= Dateadd(mi, 970, CONVERT(DATETIME, 
                                          CONVERT(DATE, [date]))) 
   ) t1 
WHERE  seqnum = 1
```

Comment: Thanks! - this gets what I wanted, now I just need to display this in a gridview with accounts as columns and date as rows. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A big part of the challenge here is that you are changing the "day" boundary from midnight to 4:10 p.m.  My approach creates a new variable called `WorkingDay` that ends at this time.  It does this by subtracting (16*60+10) minutes from the [date] and then adding one more day (to get the right corresponding calendar date).

The next step is to use `row_number()` to choose the last value on each WorkingDay:

```
select WorkingDay, account, balance
from (select h.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by account, WorkingDay order by [date] desc) as seqnum
      from (select h.*,
                   cast([date]+1-(16*60+10)/(24*60.0) as DATE) as WorkingDay
            from history h
           ) h
     ) h
where seqnum = 1
```

Comment: select DATEADD(mi,970,DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, [Date]), 0)) from History gets all days with 4:10:00 PM time.  replacing select h.*,
cast([date]+1-(16*60+10)/(24*60.0) as DATE) still doesn't work however.

Comment: @user2300404 . . . I find it easier to use "datetime + constant" for adding days (and date parts).  You should get the same effect with a similar expression, such as `dateadd(mi, 24*60-(14*60+10), [date])` or something equivalent.